# Site Header disappeared

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu, header

I was just simply editing my Wordpress site using Elementor to build out a page.  Now, my entire header (logo and menu) are gone!  I checked the source code and it doesn't appear there.  I've done some research and tried several things:

- Checking "Customize" to make sure all the settings were correct (they were)
- Going into Appearance>Menu and making sure it was still there
- Under Menu, I went to "Manage Locations" and it was correct
- I went into the CSS to make sure that there was no code blocking it and everything looked normal.

We have not updated Wordpress recently (it's still on the latest version) and we disabled all the unnecessary plugins.

The website is http://209.35.52.135/~masterclerkofcou/

The footer is also missing but that is not as important.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Set it as a primary menu. It's a check box somewhere in menus options.

Check your console log for errors.

Comment: It is already set as the primary menu and the console log shows no errors

Answer (score 0):

add:

```
z-index: 1;
```

to the CSS file.

Comment: It was set to 1 already.  So, I added a few more 0s after and it still has not shown up

Comment: or you can do this:

Comment: z-index: 1 !important